# Understanding a combinatorial equality

Tags: combinatorics

I want to understant why ${n}\choose{0}$${n}\choose{n}$ $+$ ${n}\choose{1}$${n}\choose{n-1}$ $+...+$ ${n}\choose{n}$${n}\choose{0}$ $=$ ${2n}\choose{n}$

the proof doesn't have to be analytical (although if it is, I wouldn't mind either). I would simply want to understand the equality.

(I am aware that ${n}\choose{0}$${n}\choose{n}$ $+$ ${n}\choose{1}$${n}\choose{n-1}$ $+...+$ ${n}\choose{n}$${n}\choose{0}$ $=$ ${2n}\choose{n}$ = $\Sigma_{k=0}^n$ ${n}\choose{k}$$^2$)

Comment: Particular case of Chu-Vandermonde convolution ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have $2n$ objects,
and you want to find
the number of ways
of choosing $n$ of them,
this is directly
$\binom{2n}{n}$.

Another way is to
first choose $n$
and then choose $k$ of them.
This can be done in
$\binom{n}{k}$
ways.
Then choose
$n-k$ of the other $n$.
This can be done in
$\binom{n}{n-k}$
ways.

Do this for
$k$ from $0$ to $n$.
This can be done in
$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\binom{n}{n-k}
$
ways.

These two are therefore equal.

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice bijective proof of this. Write the set of $2n$ elements in order and draw a line in the middle, so there are $n$ elements to the left and $n$ to the right. If you're choosing a set of $n$ elements from this set, you can split the subset into the piece to the left of the line and the piece to the right. The summation of products of binomial coefficients splits this computation up into disjoint exhaustive cases; $0$ to the left and $n$ to the right; $1$ to the left and $n-1$ to the right, etc.